# User-friendly link to attached images for a certain post?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, media-library

I have set up a slideshow running on the front page of my site that runs on images attached to a page called 'Home'.

I would like to be able to adjust its contents and order from the admin area. And lo, I can do this, by going to the 'Home' page in pages, clicking on the Media Library, going to the 'Gallery' tab and reordering/editing each of the attached images.

But this is not very convenient for the person who will use the site.

Can anyone recommend a plugin that allows for very simple management of attachments for a given post? Even if it's just a link I can place it in a metabox on the Dashboard and they needn't follow the above tortuous route to get to where they need to be.

Thanks!

Comment: I set up a site recently that uses a custom post type for the slideshow rather than images attached to a page. The post type allows one image each to be uploaded (as "featured image"). Adding/removing images works like adding/removing Pages. Reordering uses the "Order" property just like Pages, which can be accessed from the "Quick Edit" link. More or less confusing than your method? Close call. Image management in WordPress BEGS for improvement.

Comment: That sounds marginally better, but still bad. I wonder if one could craft an AJAX request in a link, such that it opened the floating  Media Library set to the appropriate page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gallery tab of the Media Uploader for an individual post is located at this link:
http://example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/media-upload.php?post_id=999&tab=gallery
(change the post ID as needed.)

I have no idea how robust this is, but I did a quick test on my own site, and the changes I made were saved correctly.